# C# windows app don't wait for child process

Tags: c#, .net, process

I'm starting a child process using :

```
var proc = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
       FileName = _pathChildProc,
       Arguments = sb.ToString(),
       UseShellExecute = false,
       //CreateNoWindow = false
    }
};
proc.Start();
```

---

I'm using "UseShellExecute = false" so that the process is created directly without an intermediary console.

I just want to start the child process and forget about it, so that I can quit the main app before the child process has exited. It can also be that I create more of these child processes from a single main app instance and I don't want to wait for all of them to finish.

The problem is that in the main app even after the main thread is done, the app is waiting until the child process finishes.

How can I specify that I don't want to wait for the child process?

**Edit**

I just created 2 test consols apps : "MainApp", "ChildApp". MainApp creates ChildApp as describe above.

Now the funny part: If you start the MainApp with the debugger attached (F5) than it doesn't wait for the child app, but if you run the MainApp without the debugger (Ctrl + F5) than it waits for the child.

MainApp:

```
    using System.Diagnostics;

    namespace TestDontWaitForChildProcess
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var proc = new Process
                {
                    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                    {
                        FileName = "abc\\Projects\\TestDontWaitForChildProcess\\ChildProc\\bin\\Release\\ChildProc.exe",
                        Arguments = "a",
                        UseShellExecute = false,
                        //CreateNoWindow = false
                    }
            };
            proc.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

ChildApp:

```
using System.Threading;

namespace ChildProc
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(15000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I've just tried a pair of simple apps, and it worked fine. Are you sure you don't have code elsewhere waiting for `proc`?

Comment: I just created 2 test consols apps : "MainApp", "ChildApp". MainApp creates ChildApp as describe above. Now the funny part: If you start the MainApp with the debugger attached (F5) than it doesn't wait for the child app, but if you run the MainApp without the debugger (Ctrl + F5) than it waits for the child.

Comment: So if you've got complete programs demonstrating the problem, please include them in your question. (I've got complete programs demonstrating the lack of a problem...)

Comment: @ Jon Skeet.  Does the code that I pasted also work by you?

Comment: Well that's basically the same code as I had - but I had more logging to show what time everything happened. I was running without a debugger (just from the console).

Comment: I've just tried this in VS, and it it looks like it's only VS that's the issue - your MainApp process *is* terminating - it's just that Visual Studio isn't stopping. Presumably in some cases that's useful. But when you're running outside VS, it shouldn't be an issue at all.

Comment: I did it with a workaround : UseShellExecute = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = false,
                    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden. This will use the shell so small overhead but at least will not block the MainApp and also there will be no Console window popping up.